# Why use ThreadStart?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Can somebody please clarify why we use ThreadStart?

```
new Thread (new ThreadStart (Update)).Start(); -Versus-
new Thread (Update).Start(); // Seems more straightforward

private void Update() { }
```

Comment: Your issue is with delegates in general, not threading.

Comment: Probably just because the short version wasn't possible in early C# versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can somebody please clarify why we use ThreadStart?

You don't have to. If you do, only you can say why...

Since C# 2, method groups (i.e. references to a method via its name) are implicitly convertible to delegates with the same signature. Since the `Thread` constructor takes a `ThreadStart`, you can pass it a method group with the same signature as `ThreadStart`.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to use it in your example.
**ThreadStart** is an object that holds a function that can be used to start a thread.

You'd use it for example if you have a list of functions which you want to start, put them in a list, and loop through them.