# Why can i pass a function name to the System.Threading.Thread constructor

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Im confused. The docs say a ThreadStart or ParametrizedThreadStart delegate is expected, but a method reference can be passed. How come it accepts a simple reference to a method, why is there no constructor signature that specifically determines this? Or is a delegate functionally identical to a method reference when it comes to type checking? 
Im kind of inexperienced when it comes to .net, and this is very confusing to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One line of code worth few paragraphs sometimes...

Comment: When you pass the name of a function it will create a delegate to the function which inferes the params/return types from the function signature, so at the end the compiled code will be the same.

Comment: Or maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6056983/1997232)?

Comment: That second suggestion is far better because it's discussing the implicit conversion of method groups to delegates which I think is what the OP is confused by. Alas, already closed linking to the wrong question.

Comment: Thanks, that second question really nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

A delegate *is* a "method reference" of sorts, and by definition a reference to a method is too. So the two are equivalent:

```
var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyMethod));
// or
var thread = new Thread(MyMethod); // Assuming Mymethod conforms to the right spec
```